# Create distinct list of params with list of params using nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

Giving a list of objects with different params, how to group param values into a list and bind it to another one: I'm trying out with dictionary in c# :
Example: class car : (Update : using the good solution, working code to get nested dico)

```
public class Car{

    public int Id;
    public Color Color;

}

public class Color
{
    public int Id;
    public string ColorName;
}


public static void Main()
{
    var carList = new List<Car> {
        new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 1, ColorName = "blue" }},
            new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 1, ColorName = "blue" }},
            new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 2, ColorName = "red" }},
            new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 3, ColorName = "green" }},
    };

    var carColorMap = GetCarscolorsMap(carList);

 public static Dictionary<Id, Dictionary<Id, Color>> GetCarscolorsMap(List<Car> carList)
    {
        return carList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Color})
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Id)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => v.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Color.Id, val => val.Color));
    }
}
```

Comment: it's unclear what you want from this question,   do you want a list of the distinct car colors per car?

Comment: e.g also please provide actual sample data e.g will there be a case where there is multiple color of the same car added to the list alreaddy?

Comment: yes, it's a list of the distinct car colors per car.

Comment: okay Hold on ill post a proper answer in a second

Comment: I've posted an answer,  if that answer's your question please remember to upvote and click the green check to resolve ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should just modify your architecture, to make this simpler, e.g create a table in the db which represent which color options you have to offer per car type.

With that being said, here is a sample which does it using your current architecture.  There are a few ways of doing this, I chose what make sense to me the most. First you group by a composite Key, Id And color.  Then group by just the id so you have a group of groups, from there your selecting out the first car with that color.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mIaxdT) to show it working

```
public class Car{

    public int Id;
    public Color Color;

}

public class Color
{
    public int Id;
    public string ColorName;
}


public static void Main()
{
    var carList = new List<Car> {
        new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 1, ColorName = "blue" }},
            new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 1, ColorName = "blue" }},
            new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 2, ColorName = "red" }},
            new Car() { Id = 1, Color = new Color {Id = 3, ColorName = "green" }},
    };

    var carColorMap = carList.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, ColorId = x.Color.Id}).GroupBy(x => x.Key.Id).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => v.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()));

    foreach(var car in carColorMap)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(car.Key);
        foreach(var color in car.Value)

        Console.WriteLine(color.Color.ColorName);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to implement the solution with my work, as result I'm getting one object as wanted for the Key, but for the Value, I'm just getting a Current param as null

Comment: @Justforfun I've verifed this code and it works, My guess is that you've attempted to switch it to used Color the Object instead of Color.Id, H/O I'll update the example

Comment: I used your solution to get what i'm looking for, and i updated my code. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

When reading

```
var listOfCars = new list<Car>();
var firstCar = new Car(firstCarId,fisrtCarColor);
var secondCar = new Car(firstCarId,secondCarColor);
var thirdCar = new Car(firstCarId,thirdCarColor);
listOfCars.Add(firstCar);
listOfCars.Add(secondCar);
listOfCars.Add(thirdCar);
```

it looks like you only need 1 car containing 3 colors. So either you over-simplified your code and it doesn't reflect the reality or your solution is over-engineered and makes things look complicated. You could then simplify your desing like below to get something easier:

```
public sealed class Car
{
    private readonly HashSet<Color> _colors;
    public Car(Id id, params Color[] colors)
    {
        Id = id;
        _colors = new HashSet<Color>(colors);
    }
    public Id Id { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Color> Colors => _colors;
}
```

Usage:

```
var car = new Car(carId, color1, color2, color3);

Console.WriteLine(car.Id);
foreach (var color in car.Colors)
{
    Console.WriteLine(color);
}
```

Comment: yes maybe I couldn't really explain what I clearly need, I want just to create a list of a dictionary: List<Dictionary<CarId, Dictionary<ColorId, Color>>>